Is there a word or phrase describing a group of people that turned against one person
A family of people turned on another family member because one in the group that turned gave false information about the one they turned away from.

Is there a specific word in your language?  What is that word?  What does a bilingual dictionary translate it as?  If there is no specifici word in your language, why do you expect there to be a word in English?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are probably lots of expressions but they might have different nuances and you have given only minimal information about the context. We don't know what that "false information" entails.
A group that excludes people for superficial reasons may be called a "clique".
A group that comes together in opposition of someone or something may be called a "gang" or a "mob", and the act of opposition may be called "ganging up on" the outside individual.
The act of unfairly blaming an individual for something may be called "scapegoating" from the point of view of onlookers who have a more balanced view.
An individual who unfairly persecutes an individual is usually just called a "bully", and if they get a group or gang together to support them those other individuals may be called lackeys, followers or, more dramatically, minions.

Ostracism:

exclusion from a society or group.

Ostracize:

exclude (someone) from a society or group.

